# How to estimate the norm of Jacobi fields or to compute $\langle J(0),J'(0)\rangle$

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I tried to ask this question firstly at MSE but it did not get too much attention so I decided to post it here. I am sorry if this is not appropriate do this site.

There is a classical formula based on Taylor series for the square norm of a Jacobi field $J$ with $J(0) = 0$ along a geodesic on a Riemannian manifold $M$. I am interested on a possible estimate for the square norm of a Jacobi field $J$ such that $J(0) = X\neq 0$. Or simply, it would be nice to understand the relation between $J(0)$ and $J'(0)$ in the case $J(0)\neq 0$. Can we guarantee under any assumption that $\langle J(0),J'(0)\rangle \neq 0$?

The relation between these two quantities is that one can estimate the hessian of the distance function in terms of the first derivative of $\|J(t)\|^2$ for some appropriate Jacobi field $J$ and it would be nice to me to have $\frac{d}{dt}\|J(t)\|^2\Big|_{t=0} = \langle J(0),J'(0)\rangle \neq 0$.

Comment: Note that $J(0)$ and $J'(0)$ may be chosen linearly independently. That is, Jacobi fields are solutions of a second order linear ode and so determined uniquely by $J(0)$ and $J'(0)$. In fact the space of Jacobi fields (usually taken to be orthogonal to the geodesic) is a vector space isomorphic to the finite dimensional vector space spanned by possible choices of $J(0)$ and $J'(0)$ - that is $\gamma^{\perp} \oplus \gamma^{\perp}$. So there is no general relation between $J(0)$ and $J'(0)$ - they may be chose linearly independently.

Comment: I guess that means we can guarantee $\langle J(0), J'(0) \rangle \ne 0$ simply by choosing $J$ to be the Jacobi field determined by such $J(0)$, $J'(0)$.

Comment: @PaulBryan thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.